# How to secure WCF Service with NetTCPRelayBinding

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF Service using nettcprelay binding and I want to make it secure.

I can not use transport level windows authentication as it is going to be access over internet with tcp protocol. If I am not mistaken it is only for HTTP Protocol.

I am planning to use Message Security with Username option.

Need to know whether it is a right approach or not?